# Tags [soreness] [muscle-soreness] [doms] are quite the same

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness)(26 tagged), [soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soreness) (6)  and [doms](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doms) (3) are pretty all about the same thing.

There are two questions under [soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soreness) that don't seem to be directly related to muscles. The others could be retagged or are already tagged with [muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness).

Or maybe unify all those tags under the most common denominator [soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soreness)?

Comment: DOMS is a subset of muscle soreness, not an equivalent set.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann muscle soreness is a subset of soreness, too. My question here is, if we need all those tags or if one is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say we don't have enough questions about soreness to have 3 different tags for them. I'd also venture to say that we won't likely have many on-topic questions that have need of the tag [soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soreness), as any soreness not related to [muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness) probably requires a doctor and is out of scope for this site.

Under [soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soreness) we have at least 2 **very** borderline for being out-of-scope:

- [I hurt my back from a deadlift attempt. When can I go back to weight lifting?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7321/i-hurt-my-back-from-a-deadlift-attempt-when-can-i-go-back-to-weight-lifting)
- [joint problem during workout](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/joint-problem-during-workout)

The only question which isn't about [muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness) of the remaining questions, "[How to reduce shoulder soreness during and after squats](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-to-reduce-shoulder-soreness-during-and-after-squats)", is more about bruising type pain than [muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness). Since [doms](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doms) is a subset of [muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness), I think we should probably close the borderline questions, and retag everything to [muscle-soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-soreness) except the "shoulder soreness" question, and find a creative way to retag it ([shoulders](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoulders) + [pain](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pain)).